# II CELL VALIDATION IN EXCEL II

Tags: excel, validation, cell

I want to validate cell value only letters should be allowed at least six and more?

I have tried but I have failed I want to get answers through you I am sure you will try to give me the answer I want as soon as possible?

Answer (score 1):

Dear NARESH VIJAYKUMAR SHINDE

I have done the same thing as you require before, hope you enjoy the solution
You can find the solution on the Microsoft website as an attached link,

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/apply-data-validation-to-cells-29fecbcc-d1b9-42c1-9d76-eff3ce5f7249

Answer (score 1):

If the cell is `A1`, you can test it as follow:

```
=IF(ISTEXT(A1), IF(LEN(A1) > 5, TRUE, FALSE), "Not a text")
```

If you mean Data Validation Excel functionality, you can define the rule as follow:

[image: Excel Data Validation Window]

If you enter a text that is shorter and if you defined an Error Alert message you get the following:

[image: In case of error]